# How to get the session data into Codeigniter controller after user logged in?

Tags: codeigniter, session, controller

I want to access session data after the user has logged in. I'm able to access session data in view pages but I want to access in the controller as well to create some database tables with session data like user id, name etc.

Comment: How you are getting session data in view?

Comment: Like this

$this->session->userdata('user_id');

Comment: Same way to access in the controller. So, What is the issue?

Comment: I tried the same in controller, But I'm not getting the session data.

Comment: add code that you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

You can get session data:

```
$session = $this->session->userdata('session_name'); //Replace 'session_name' to your session name

print_r($session); //For check
```

You can details from [Click Here](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html)

Answer (score 0):

first set session variable in login controller as- 
$this->session->set_userdata('userid', $row->iduser);

and use that session variable as-
$this->session->userdata('userid');

Answer (score 0):

Following line will show all session data.

```
    $session_data = $this->session->userdata();
    echo "<pre>"; print_r($session_data); exit;
```